# TCP: client sends [RST, ACK] after client send [FIN, ACK]

Tags: tcp

as the picture shown below, in a http request from chrome browser, after recieved all bytes of the wav file, the client sends [FIN, ACK] to server and a [RST, ACK] to server, so the "Broken pipe" IOException occurs in java program
[tcp picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M10Kz.png)

Java full Exception below, "Broken pipe" means the tcp connection was cut off, the program is build by SpringBoot and run in Linux. When the same code in native Windows, everything goes fine:

```
// Exception
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:171)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:141)
    at com.cc.ai.tts.AiTtsController.tts(AiTtsController.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:353)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:157)
        at com.cc.ai.tts.AiTtsController.tts(AiTtsController.java:97)
        ... 54 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:469)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:135)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:766)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:586)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:530)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:547)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:73)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:194)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340)
        ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:469)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:135)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:766)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:586)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:530)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:547)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:194)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Comment: So, catch the exception? There's not enough detail to give meaningful advice here.

Comment: the exception has been pasted above, thanks for your watching

Comment: The stack trace shows that the exception occurred when sending the HTTP response back since the client has already closed the connection. Unfortunately this by its own is neither enough to understand the problem, nor to replicate it and therefore also not enough to help you solve it. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how you should proceed to provide the information which are needed to help you.